# Script in /etc/ssh/sshrc ignore for one user

Tags: server, scripts, ssh

As I've read on couple threads, I configured a script in /etc/ssh/sshrc for it to send an E-Mail every time when somebody connects over SSH. That works pretty good but recently I started using ansible to automate Linux Updates.
Ansible opens multiple SSH connections which sends too many E-Mails for each system.
What I want to do, is not use that script /etc/ssh/sshrc just for ansible user. I already tried creating empty file  /home/USER/.ssh/rc
But that did not work.
What am I doing wrong OR is there any other way to limit that to only one E-Mail?

Comment: Put a condition into the script /etc/ssh/sshrc itself to check what user is logging in, and don't send the mail if it's the user you want to ignore.

Comment: Does the server's config set `PermitUserRC no`? that might explain why `/home/USER/.ssh/rc` gets ignored

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1463292/1372403

Comment: No. I tried setting it to yes but no difference. Now it is default.